# Add row for each group with missing value

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

The total number of fruits each basket can hold is 10. For each basket, if the count is 10 and there is a fruit missing, I'd like to add a row for that basket that says 0 for the count of that fruit. 
 Here is the code to generate the dataframe.

```
Basket <- c("A","A","B","B","C","C","C")
Fruit <- c("Apple","Orange","Apple","Orange","Orange","Apple", "Guava")
count <- c("5","5","7","3","2","6","4")
data <- data.frame(Basket,Fruit,count)

  Basket  Fruit count
1      A  Apple     5
2      A Orange     5
3      B  Apple     7
4      B  Guava     3
5      C Orange     2
6      C  Apple     6
7      C  Guava     4
```

I'd basically like it to look like this:

```
Basket  Fruit count
1      A  Apple     5
2      A Orange     5
4      A  Guava     0
5      B  Apple     7
6      B Orange     0
7      B  Guava     3
8      C Orange     2
9      C  Apple     6
10     C  Guava     4
```

Not exactly sure if looping would be an efficient method but open to suggestions. The goal is to get an accurate mean across groups for each fruit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert your data.frame to wide format, filling it with 0s instead of NAs, then convert it back to tall format:

```
count <- c(5,5,7,3,2,6,4)       # should be integers, not strings
data <- data.frame(Basket,Fruit,count)

d1 <- tidyr::spread( data, Fruit, count, fill = 0 )
d2 <- tidyr::gather( d1, Fruit, count, -Basket )
```

Comment: Nvm. This worked!

Comment: The complaint about mismatching attributes might be due to character variables being treated as `factors`. Try adding `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to your `data.frame` construction. Or better yet, use `tibble::data_frame` instead.

Answer (score 2):

i know with spread and gather funcion, from tydir package

```
library(tidyr)
data <- data %>%
  spread(Fruit, count, fill = 0) %>%
  gather(Fruit, count, -Basket)
```

to put 0, count values must be integer, not factor.
You can do this with

```
data$count <- as.integer(data$count))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data <- data.frame(Basket,Fruit,count,stringsAsFactors = F)
full = merge(
    data,
    expand.grid(
        Basket=data$Basket,
        Fruit=data$Fruit
    ),
    all.y=T
)
full$count = ifelse(is.na(full$count), 0, full$count)
```

Comment: Quinn, thank you for this answer. It does work actually, but I realized for my dataset the Basket is a GUID which isn't possible to list out.

Comment: What about with the change that I just made?

Comment: My data frame is too large for this to work. I get an error saying
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 405.1 Gb

Answer (score 0):

The count only works if there is only 1 missing level of Fruit, otherwise should work as intended

```
Basket <- c("A","A","B","B","C","C","C")
Fruit <- c("Apple","Orange","Apple","Orange","Orange","Apple", "Guava")
count <- c(5,5,7,3,2,6,4)
data <- data.frame(Basket,Fruit,count, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

fruit_levels <- levels(as.factor(data$Fruit))
append_df <- data.frame(Basket = NA, Fruit = NA, count = NA)

for(i in levels(as.factor(data$Basket))){
    temp_df <- filter(data, Basket == i)
    temp_count <- 10 - sum(temp_df$count)
    if(length(levels(as.factor(temp_df$Fruit))) != length(fruit_levels)){

        temp_fruit <- cbind.data.frame(fruit = fruit_levels, count = ifelse(fruit_levels %in% temp_df$Fruit, 0, 1))
        temp_fruit2 <- filter(temp_fruit, count == 1) %>% select(fruit)
        temp_fruit3 <- temp_fruit2[,1] %>% as.character()

        temp_df_to_append <- data.frame(Basket = i, Fruit = temp_fruit3, count = temp_count)
        append_df <- rbind.data.frame(append_df, temp_df_to_append)
    }
}

data <- rbind.data.frame(data, append_df[-1,]) %>% arrange(Basket)
```