# adding rows by group to get same number of observations by group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, data-cleaning

I have what seems like a pretty simple question, but I haven't been able to successfully adapt solutions to similar ones to my situation, including this one: [Add row for each group with missing value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446173/add-row-for-each-group-with-missing-value)

I have some data that looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 265 x 4
   anon_ID assistance_date Benefit_1 nth_assistance_interaction
     <int> <chr>           <chr>                          <dbl>
 1       8 2020-04-10      Medical                            5
 2       8 2020-04-13      Medical                           10
 3       8 2020-04-15      Medical                           15
 4       8 2020-04-21      Medical                           20
 5      11 2020-06-17      Housing                            5
 6      11 2020-06-25      Financial                         10
 7      11 2021-01-27      Financial                         15
 8      26 2020-05-18      Legal                              5
 9      26 2021-06-01      Food                              10
10      26 2021-08-02      Utilities                         15
# ... with 255 more rows
```

I want to modify it so that each `anon_ID` has four observations, one for each unique value of `nth_assistance_interaction`. The values of `assistance_date` and `Benefit_1` should be `NA` when real values for these variables don't exist.

e.g., for `anon_ID` = `11`, these two variables would have `NA` values when `nth_assistance_interaction` = `20`.

```
# A tibble: 265 x 4
   anon_ID assistance_date Benefit_1 nth_assistance_interaction
     <int> <chr>           <chr>                          <dbl>
 1       8 2020-04-10      Medical                            5
 2       8 2020-04-13      Medical                           10
 3       8 2020-04-15      Medical                           15
 4       8 2020-04-21      Medical                           20
 5      11 2020-06-17      Housing                            5
 6      11 2020-06-25      Financial                         10
 7      11 2021-01-27      Financial                         15
 8      11 NA              NA                                20
 9      26 2020-05-18      Legal                              5
10      26 2021-06-01      Food                              10
11      26 2021-08-02      Utilities                         15
# ... with 255 more rows
```

This is just one example of what I'm trying to accomplish. It could also be the case that `anon_ID` = `27` only has one observation for `nth_assistance_interaction`, and so I would need to add three rows for them.

How can I go about making this happen? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may group by 'anon_ID' and use `complete` to expand the data

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %> 
  group_by(anon_ID) %>% 
  complete(nth_assistance_interaction = c(5, 10, 15, 20)) %>% 
  ungroup
```